# Display Data from Backend in Ionic

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework, frontend, backend

I have a `user.service`, a `list.page.ts` and a `list.page.html`.

And I want to display data from the backend (php). I am getting Data in the console log, but it doesn't display on the website. Please Help.
Thank you!

`user.servive`

```
    export enum SearchType {
    all = '',
    name = 'name',
    stadt = 'stadt'
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/getallrestaurants';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  searchData(name: string, type: SearchType): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/getallrestaurants')
    .pipe(
        map(results => {
            console.log('RAW: ', results);
            return results['Search'];
        })
    );
  }
```

`list.page.ts`

```
export class ListPage implements OnInit {


    results: Observable<any>;
    searchTerm = '';
    type: SearchType = SearchType.all;

    constructor(private userService: UserService) { }


    ngOnInit() {}

    searchChanged() {
        this.results = this.userService.searchData(this.searchTerm, this.type);

    }
```

`list.page.html`

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionChange)="searchChanged($event)"></ion-searchbar>

<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Select Searchtype</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="type" (ionChange)="searchChanged($event)">
        <ion-select-option value="">All</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="stadt">Stadt</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="name">Name</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item button *ngFor="let item of (results | async)" [routerLink]="['/', 'list', item.imdbID ]">
        <ion-icon [name]="item.icon" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <p>Hallo User: {{item.name}}</p>
      </ion-item>
```

[This is my console.log, as you see i get the data, now i want it to show for example the name on frontend.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prZvn.png)

Comment: You should console log or debug inside of `searchChanged()` to see if `this.results` gets updated in `list.page.ts`. If it doesn't there's another issue going on here within your service having to do with returning an observable. You must subscribe to the observable in order to retrieve data from it. That is ```searchChanged() {
        this.userService.searchData(this.searchTerm, this.type).subscribe(res => this.results = res);

    }```

Comment: what is exactly problem ? You can't get data from backend ? You can get data from backend but nothing to show on frontend ? I wonder if the results is empty (using `console.log` to check it).

Comment: In the console.log i get the data from backend, like name, city etc. My problem is that it doesn't show the data in frontend. I want to display for example the name on frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see the problem here in the class user.service you have to change it like this.

```
searchData(name: string, type: SearchType): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/getallrestaurants')
    .pipe(
        map(results => {
            console.log('RAW: ', results);
            return results;
        })
    );
  }
```

You have to remove the ['Search'] because your JSON Response has no entry which is like 'Search'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing `console.log` update then this is most likely an issue with the html template not knowing some data changed that it needs to re-render and update the view for. Angular has built in change detection strategy but as the developer you can also manually interact with it. Checkout (https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) for further explanation on this topic.

As for your code, try inserting the change detection reference as so by importing `ChangeDetectorRef` from `@angular/core`, and then check for changes of data to tell the view to re-render.

`list.page.ts`

```
export class ListPage implements OnInit {


    results: Observable<any>;
    searchTerm = '';
    type: SearchType = SearchType.all;

    constructor(private userService: UserService, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {}

    searchChanged() {
        this.results = this.userService.searchData(this.searchTerm, this.type);
        this.ref.detectChanges()
    }
```

**Note:** this will execute every time the user types and it may slow down your application because you're forcing angular to check for changes every time you call `searchChanged()`. I would thereby implement some sort of debounce technique to stall redundant or unnecessary calls to `searchChanged()`. Check out this resources to learn more about debouncing if this issue comes up (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounce).